# How to check if an expression contains a symbol ONLY after a given head?

Tags: pattern-matching

I have just started programming in *Mathematica* and still have to get a hang of it (and rule-based programming), so I apologize if this question may seem stupid. I will explain it with a concrete example.

I have an expression which is an inequality, and I have to determine if the unknown variable appears under a square root (the expression might also not contain any square roots at all).

So, my first thought was to use `FreeQ`:

```
FreeQ[expr, Sqrt[x]]
```

The problem occurs when `x` appears at deeper levels of the expression tree under `Sqrt`.

For example,

```
expr = 3 Sqrt[2 x + 9] + 23/ 7 x^2 >= 0
```

so the `FullForm` is

```
GreaterEqual[Plus[..., Times[3, Power[Plus[9, Times[2, x]], Rational[1, 2]]]], 0]
```

So I can't use `Sqrt[___x___]` or `x_Sqrt` as it's head is `Times`, and not `Power`.

Is there anyway I can build a pattern to use with `FreeQ` or is there any other function that can determine if a given expression contains a symbol AFTER a given head (e.g., `Power[(something with x), 1/2]` as in my case).

Comment: Consider `Cases[3 Sqrt[2 x + 9] + Sqrt[a + 2] + 23/7 x^2 >= 0, Sqrt[expr_] /; ! FreeQ[expr, x], ∞]`

Comment: `FreeQ[expr,  Power[something : __, Rational[1, 2]] /; Not[FreeQ[something, x]]]`? or `FreeQ[expr, Sqrt[something : __] /; Not[FreeQ[something, x]]]`

Comment: These work! Thank you very much!

Comment: Possibly of interest: [(5682963)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5682963/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two ways to do it taken from comments to the question.

kglr and J.M.

```
With[{expr = 3 Sqrt[2 x + 9] + Sqrt[a + 2] + 23/7 x^2 >= 0}, 
  Cases[expr, Sqrt[something_] /; ! FreeQ[something, x], ∞]]
```

kglr

```
With[{expr = 3 Sqrt[2 x + 9] + Sqrt[a + 2] + 23/7 x^2 >= 0}, 
  Cases[expr, Power[something : __, Rational[1, 2]] /; Not[FreeQ[something, x]], ∞]]
```