# Cases do not pick up Sqrt?

Tags: filtering, searching

I'm trying to understand how `Cases` work in Mathematica, and I'm a bit curios why i't wont pick up the Sqrt function?

Consider the following expressions

```
Cases[Erfc[b], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[a*Erfc[b], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[a*Sqrt[b], _Sqrt, Infinity]
Cases[a*Sqrt[b], _Sqrt, Infinity]
Cases[a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b], _Sqrt, Infinity]
```

they give respectively

```
{}
{Erfc[b]}
{}
{}
{Erfc[b]}
{}
```

Why does `Cases` fail in the cases that give `{}`?

Comment: See `FullForm[Sqrt[x]]`. It returns `Power[x, Rational[1, 2]]` which corresponds to `x^(1/2)`, and either you have to prevent evaluation or match this form.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114685

Comment: Also: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221369, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22948

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case:

```
Cases[Erfc[b], _Erfc, Infinity]
```

"Infinity" means: {1,Infinity}. But Erfc[b] is at level 0. Therefore, you need:

```
Cases[Erfc[b], _Erfc, {0,Infinity}]
```

Further, the next problem:

```
Cases[a*Sqrt[b], _Sqrt, Infinity]
```

The full form of Sqrt[b] is Power[..] (You may use "FullForm" to see the full form). Therefore, you need:

```
Cases[a*Sqrt[b], _Power,  Infinity]
```

To get:

```
{Sqrt[b]}
```

Then the case of:

Cases[a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b], _Sqrt, Infinity]

Because arguments are evaluated before sending them to functions, a*Sqrt[a] is simplified to a^(3/2) and by:

```
Cases[a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b], _Power, Infinity]
```

you get:

```
{a^(3/2)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check `FullForm`, arg of `Cases` is evaluated before matching:

```
FullForm[a*Sqrt[b]]
Cases[HoldForm[a*Sqrt[b]], _Sqrt, Infinity]

MatchQ[f[x], f[x]]
Symbol === Head[f]
Cases[f[x], _f, Infinity]
Cases[{f[x]}, _f, Infinity]
```

Comment: Does this also explain why `Cases[Erfc[b], _Erfc, Infinity]` gives `{}`?

Comment: @MikaelFremling, no, this seems to be related to expression `Head` being a symbol, see the edit, not sure why

Comment: @MikaelFremling Try `Cases[Erfc[b], _Erfc, {0, Infinity}]`.  The level spec `Infinity` is equivalent to `{1, Infinity}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try HoldForm

```
Cases[HoldForm[ Erfc[b]], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[HoldForm[ a*Erfc[b]], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[HoldForm[ a*Sqrt[b]], _Sqrt, Infinity]
Cases[HoldForm[ a*Sqrt[b]], _Sqrt, Infinity]
Cases[HoldForm[ a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b]], _Erfc, Infinity]
Cases[HoldForm[ a*Sqrt[a]*Erfc[b]], _Sqrt, Infinity]
```

[image]